# Setting MaxConnectionsPerServer in HttpClientHandler fails

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, .net-standard

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms application, which should run on iOS, Android and UWP. 
This application uses an HttpClient to communicate with other resources. The HttpClient usage is capsulated in a `.NET Standard 2.0` library. The library works fine in other application (Mainly used in a `ASP.NET` environment).
The library uses an instance of the [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netstandard-2.0) to configure the HttpClient. Inside of the `HttpClientHandler` the sets the [`MaxConnectionsPerServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClientHandler_MaxConnectionsPerServer) property to `1`. This leads to an `System.ArgumentException` with the following informations:
`Message`:

> "Wrong parameter r\n\r\nvalue"

`StackTrace`:

> at
> Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter.put_MaxConnectionsPerServer(UInt32
> value)
>     at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_MaxConnectionsPerServer(Int32
> value)

The rest of the fields inside the exception are `null`  (for example `ParamName`, `Source`, ...)
The same error appears when it is used without the reference to a library.
It is easy to reproduce this error:

1. Create a new blanc Xamarin application
2. Add in the constructor of the `MainPage` the line:
   `var handler = new HttpClientHandler(){ MaxConnectionsPerServer = 1};`
3. Run the application on Windows.

Am I missing any reference or incompatibility?

**PS:**
`Xamarin.Essentials: v1.5.3.2` 
`Xamarin.Forms: v4.8.0.1687` 
`Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlattform: v6.2.10`

**Edit:**
Referencing to the comments, my question is not clear:
The value of 1, is intended and according to the documentation, there is nothing written, that this isn't allowed. We only want a single connection per server and not more! In addition in an other environment (`ASP.NET Core`) the value of 1 is totaly fine and does not throw the Exception.
**So why does the behaviour in Xamarin.Forms is not consistent to other environments?**

Comment: What is your question?  Why not increase the MaxConnectionsPerServer count?

Comment: Why are you trying to set such a weird value? Last century the conventional limit was 2 but in the last 10+ years applications need *more* concurrent connections per server, not less. Decreasing this can only *create* problems. If you have concurrency issues in your server, you need to fix them there. Same for the client.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I edited the question to make clear what the question is. The value of 1 is totaly intended and works in another enviroment fine! And according to the documentation the value 1 is not illegal

Comment: @TheTanic just because another environment doesn't throw doesn't mean this requirement makes sense. If you wanted to throttle requests you could ensure only one request is made at a time, not block what is supposed to be an asynchronous method. What problem is this limit trying to solve?

Comment: `why does the behaviour in Xamarin.Forms is not consistent to other environments` probably because that behavior is accidental? Or because *WinRT* on which this application runs, doesn't allow this? The snippet of the stack trace shows this was thrown by HttpBaseProtocolFilter, which is part of WinRT, not Xamarin.Forms. Any UWP application would throw the same error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The idea was to allow a single connection and over the single open connection send multiplexed requests with HTTP/2. Still it makes no sense, that one throws an exception and the other one doesn't when its using the same codebase. If this behaviour isnt consistent in all environments which use the code base. Otherwise it makes no sense to use shared code bases. If it is accidently, then the documentation has to be changed, or am i wrong?

Comment: @TheTanic but that's not what you are doing at all on the one hand. This type of behavior is controlled by the *runtime* and definitely not through that setting. This isn't an `interleave requests` setting, it's a `don't allow more requests` setting. On the other hand, the error is thrown by WinRT, not Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225724/discussion-between-thetanic-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Setting MaxConnectionsPerServer in HttpClientHandler fails

Please check `MaxConnectionsPerServer` [applies to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-5.0#applies-to) part, this property does not contain UWP platform. I'm afraid it will not work well in UWP platform. for comparing the deafferents, you could  check [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-5.0) class applies to part, it contain UWP platform.

Comment: That makes not complete sense for me: If i change the value from 1 to 2, there is no exception.
But I aggree with you, that it was my fault to think, that if the class is supported by uwp, all properties of the class are supported too

Comment: Yep, if you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app. And if above answer is helpful please consider mark it .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still i am wondering, why changing the value to 2 doesnt throw an exception

Comment: It' hard to explain, but I'm afraid even if set  `MaxConnectionsPerServer`  as 2. it may also not work.

Comment: You are right, just because it doesnt throw an exception it doesnt mean that it works. Because its officially not supported i stop here